# How to properly add a new object into the paginated field value into Apollo cache?

Tags: javascript, apollo, react-apollo

I have a complex graphql object/type that contains complex fields where value is the pagination data. One of the fields called `comments` and it contains the comments pagination data. I want to use the `optimistic-ui` approach and manually add the new Comment, when the user creates it, to the `comments` field value **before**  the server mutation execution, and in this way I expect to show the user the freshly created comment while the mutation is executing on the server.

I'm really wondering about the best way how to do that?

I tried manually create the **pagination node** and push it inside the original comments nodes however I received an error: *TypeError: Cannot add property 2, object is not extensible*
I tried to clone the original comments value to be able to modify it but nothing helps somehow.

So I'd like to interest in some way how I could handle this problem.

I'll appreciate any help/information

P.S. Here is the code examples

**The whole source Article object**

```
{
    "__typename": "Article",
    "id": "607559b181072e34ecf7af25",
    "createdAt": "2021-04-13T08:43:29.846Z",
    "liked": false,
    "likes": 0,
    "commentsThreadId": "607559b181072e34ecf7af24",
    "comments": {
        "__typename": "CommentsConnection",
        "totalCount": 2,
        "pageInfo": {
            "__typename": "PageInfo",
            "hasNextPage": false,
            "startCursor": "NjA3NTY4N2Y4MTA3MmUzNGVjZjdhZjI5",
            "endCursor": "NjA5ZTRlMmIyM2U5NmEzZGRjOTQwMTIz",
            "hasPreviousPage": false,
            "count": 2
        },
        "edges": [
            {
                "__typename": "CommentEdge",
                "node": {
                    "__typename": "Comment",
                    "id": "6075687f81072e34ecf7af29",
                    "text": "Comments like this are just amazing. YavatarImgUrlou can write whatever you want and after that, you can check the result of this. It can have more than 3 lines",
                    "liked": false,
                    "likes": 0,
                    "createdAt": "2021-04-13T09:46:39.806Z",
                    "owner": {
                        "__typename": "UserBase",
                        "id": "60658c4632aaea36205cffa2",
                        "firstName": "David",
                        "lastName": null,
                        "username": "david1",
                        "numericId": "3321"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "__typename": "CommentEdge",
                "node": {
                    "__typename": "Comment",
                    "id": "609e4e2b23e96a3ddc940123",
                    "text": "Some simple comment guys",
                    "liked": false,
                    "likes": 0,
                    "createdAt": "2021-05-14T10:17:15.057Z",
                    "owner": {
                        "__typename": "UserBase",
                        "id": "608156675ca92e56749d71fc",
                        "firstName": "Sviat",
                        "lastName": null,
                        "username": "sviat1",
                        "numericId": "9421"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "author": {
        "__typename": "User",
        "id": "60754dda81072e34ecf7af13",
        "imageUrl": null,
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Peterson",
        "username": "john1",
        "numericId": "3659"
    },
    "topics": [
        {
            "__typename": "Topic",
            "id": "60658c8c470f285c18652917",
            "name": "libsep"
        },
        {
            "__typename": "Topic",
            "id": "60658c89521b0e5c18daf3d6",
            "name": "huribu"
        }
    ]
}
```

**The code I used to update the `comments` field**

```
    const { getArticle: cachedArticle } = apolloClient.readQuery({
      query: GET_ARTICLE_QUERY,
      variables: {
        // Provide any required variables here
        id: article.id,
      },
    });
    
    const newComment = {
      __typename: "Comment",
      id: "6075687f81072e34ecf7af29",
      text: 'Shiny New Comment Text',
      liked: false,
      likes: 0,
      createdAt: "2021-04-13T09:46:39.806Z",
      owner: {
        __typename: "UserBase",
        id: "60658c4632aaea36205cffa2",
        firstName: "David",
        lastName: null,
        username: "david1",
        numericId: "3321",
      },
    };
    // Tried to create the new object that allowed to modify
    const newComments = { ...cachedArticle.comments };

    // got an error at this stage
    newComments.edges.push({
      __typename: "CommentEdge",
      node: newComment,
    });
```

Comment: you need to replace any [to be] modified object ... `newComments.edges = [...newComments.edges, {.....new edge ..}]` - read about 'immutable'

Comment: Hi @xadm. Thank you for your notice. You're right, we need to use the **deep** cloning to be sure our new objects won't refer to the old ones. I just forget this nuance)